# Displaying multiple images from one directory as one figure in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This is my first post, so apologies if I do something wrong or am not  clear.

I am trying to display multiple .fig files in one figure to compare them to each other. I tried using montage() but the education license I am on apparently doesn't have that included.

With montage I did..

```
comp10 = dir('c:\data_figs\location_1\fig10*.fig');
montage(comp10,'size',[1 NaN]);
```

Is there a way to do something similar without montage? I'm comparing ultrasound imaging analyses, and want them next to each other in order to see which ones have significant movement and which ones can be thrown out.

I am very inexperienced in matlab, so I probably am missing something super simple.

Thank you!

Comment: See  [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)